# Don't email me my resumé: send me my cover letter! And the job description!

Tags: feature-request, jobs, email

I reuse the same resumé over and over again. I actually don't need to receive a copy of my own resumé every time I apply. (I have it already.)

But what I *do* want in my inbox is **a copy of the job description**, and **a copy of what I wrote in the cover letter**.  Now that would be helpful!

Comment: Side note: tailoring a resume is a great way to get a job!

Comment: When I first read the title I thought you wanted SE to actually *mail* you your documents :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think this is a great suggestion. It's going on the Trello board (we keep a Trello board with literally every customer/user suggestion). As per usual we have **A LOT** of stuff cooking so I can't commit to if or when this would get implemented.

Comment: Any update on the status of this?